# Complex query with WP_Query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am still learning wordpress and trying to perform a query of posts with WP_Query, meta_query to be precise, the thing is after trying different possible ways and finding out that I can't nest arrays with relations I dont know if the next possible way is to make a sql query directly.

To better explain what I would like to do,  the next array hopefully will help:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'Meta_geo',
        'value'   => '46',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'Meta_dest',
        'value'   => 'si',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',

         array(
           array(
            'key'     => 'Meta_1',
            'value'   => '10',
            'compare' => '<=',
           ),
           array(
            'key'     => 'Meta_1',
            'value'   => '30',
            'compare' => '>=',
           )
         ),

         array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
           array(
            'key'     => 'Meta_1',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
           ),
           array(
            'key'     => 'Meta_1',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
           )
         )
    )
),
```

many Thanks for the time, if there are an expertet who can give me a hint I will be grateful.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: can you explain your query?

Comment: can you do your query in SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have above the below is the closest your are going to get...

```
'meta_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
        'key'     => 'Meta_geo',
         'value'   => '46',
         'compare' => '=',
     ),
    array(
       'key'     => 'Meta_dest',
       'value'   => 'si',
       'compare' => '=',
    ),

    array(
        'key'     => 'Meta_1',
        'value'   => array('10','11','12' etc),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),

 )
```

This will leave you a little sorting out to do however. This can be done with a loop and as you normally display the results of a query using the loop you can use that.

e.g.

```
 while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    $metavalue = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_geo', true);
    $metavalue = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_dist', true);// if there are a lot of conds, use get_post_meta($post->ID) to return object of value arrays

    if($metavalue == 46 && ): //proceed
       //html here!
    endif;
 endwhile;
```